# Debug C# Excel Addin via SharpDevelop on Windows

Tags: c#, excel, sharpdevelop, netoffice

I am pulling my hair out trying to debug an Excel Addin from **SharpDevelop 5.1** which I created via **NetOffice 1.7.3**.  These are the steps I've done so far: -

1. Installed **SharpDevelop 5.1**
2. Installed **NetOffice 1.7.3**
3. Ran `Developer Toolbox.exe` and clicked "Create New Project" and clicked the following: -

   1. *Project Type*

      1. `Automation Addin`
      2. Use NetOffice Tools: `checked`
      3. Project Folder: `<some dir>`
   2. *Environment*

      1. Language: `C#`
      2. Environment: `VS 2010 (Express)`
      3. .NET Runtime: `4.0 (Client Profile)`
   3. Office applications:

      1. Clicked: `Excel`
   4. Assembly Information

      1. Name: `<my name>`
      2. Description: `<my description>`
   5. Load Behavior

      1. User available to: `Current User`
      2. Decide when it has to be loaded: `3 = Load at startup`
   6. User interface.

      1. Check all 4 options
   7. Create project
4. Open project in **SharpDevelop**, select project - set compile to Set target CPU to `x86-64 processor`.

[image]

So I've been able to build the addin and run it in Excel no problem - it's just the debugging which I can't do.  Is there some setting or property which I need to set?  Any help will be much appreciated.

---

**NOTE (1)** - the *About* page in *SharpDevelop* shows the following: -

```
SharpDevelop Version : 5.1.0.5134-RC-d5052dc5
.NET Version         : 4.6.01055
OS Version           : Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
Current culture      : English (United Kingdom) (en-GB)
Running under WOW6432, processor architecture: x86-64
Working Set Memory   : 194256kb
GC Heap Memory       : 49366kb
```

**NOTE (2)** - I have already installed MS Visual Studio the but the community edition doesn't let you do Excel addin development (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398242.aspx) and IMO the `Visual Studio Professional` version is too expensive (see https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx for pricing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharpDevelop does not support 64-bit debugging.

Did you try using the VS community edition to open your existing project file?
I don't see a reason why it would refuse to build/debug a project that works in SharpDevelop.

If VS complains about invalid project types, try removing the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` element from the project file. These GUIDs just tell VS which plugins should be used to open the project; they usually don't have any effect on simple building/debugging.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  VS Community Edition works nicely with a project build in NetOffice, many thanks!